# Truncating tables in Azure Data Factory Pre-Copy script?

Tags: sql, parameters, azure-data-factory

I am building a pipeline, and now I need to truncate my destination tables in azure sql db, but before that I need to truncate the destination tables. but I can't figure out the script:

[Click to view the ADF screenshot for SINK settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yBeG.png)

instead, I put this code but that is wrong because it runs before every copy of the tables (5 times) and truncates all the table except the last one. so I need to make it parameterized I guess:

```
*truncate table [dbo].[Global_data.csv]
truncate table [dbo].[Option_data.csv]
truncate table [dbo].[State_data.csv]
truncate table [dbo].[Status_data.csv]
truncate table [dbo].[Target_data.csv]*
```

Also please see my source parameters:

```
**ADLSv2 container: @pipeline().parameters.SourceContainer
ADLSv2 Directory: @pipeline().parameters.SourceDirectory
ADLSv2 filename:  @item().name
Sink TableName:   @item().name**
```

So I'm guessing that my pre-script must be something like:
**truncate table @item().name**  but this resulted an error for me:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m50Bu.png)

**DetailsErrorCode=** `SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near '@item'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax near '@item'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect syntax near '@item'.,},],'`

when I use **TRUNCATE TABLE [@{item()}]** , I get below error 5 times (one for each table accordingly):

```
ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Cannot find the object "{"name":"StateMetadata.csv","type":"File"}" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Cannot find the object "{"name":"StateMetadata.csv","type":"File"}" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=4701,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=4701,State=1,Message=Cannot find the object "{"name":"StateMetadata.csv","type":"File"}" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.,},],'
```

Comment: Can you please share the error message that you are getting based on this expression  :truncate table @item().name 

And also what value are you iterating for in for each activity

Comment: @Nandan  I've added it to the post because it's lengthy. when I leave pre-script script blank, it runs but populate duplicate data obviously so I need to truncate each of those 5 tables empty first.

Comment: can you just try  TRUNCATE TABLE [@{item()}]

Comment: thanks. I have added that and got another error. I'll add it to the post again because it doesnt fit here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use  truncate table TRUNCATE TABLE [@{item().name}]

Comment: I'm actually using this syntax but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I still get duplicate values in the table yet there are no errors in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

This script works for me

```
@{concat('truncate table',' ','SchemaName.',item().name)}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).